# Code not running when main method is added

Tags: scala

I',m following the akka tutorial from http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/AkkaScala.pdf and below is the HelloWorld program. The main method is added by me but the I do not receive the "run as scala application" in Eclipse when I attempt to run it. According to the doc to run the program from the command line : "java -classpath  akka.Main com.example.HelloWorld" but I require to run it from Eclipse so have added my own main method. Why will the below code not run ?

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props

class HelloWorld extends Actor {

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    // create the greeter actor
    val greeter = context.actorOf(Props[Greeter], "greeter")
    // tell it to perform the greeting
    greeter ! Greeter.Greet
  }
  def receive = {
    // when the greeter is done, stop this actor and with it the application
    case Greeter.Done => context.stop(self)
  }

  object Greeter {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      new HelloWorld
    }   

    case object Greet
    case object Done


  }
  class Greeter extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case Greeter.Greet =>
        println("Hello World!")
        sender ! Greeter.Done
    }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `main` method has to be within a standalone `object`. Here you have it within an object within a `class`.